# Javascript findIndex gives recursive results

Tags: javascript

I have a table with two dropdowns in each cell and when the user changes the default value I want to record the changes, pass them to view (with a confirm buttom), and record them in the database.

I use changed_element to record the elements changed (is a list of list: type, row, column) and changed_value to record the new value. If the user change the same dropdown more times I of curse want to record only the last value, so changed_element don't admit duplicates.

This is my code:

```
...
var changed_element=[]
var changed_value=[];
var index=-1

document.getElementById('tabella').addEventListener('change', function(event){
  var elem = event.target; //detect the element changed
  var element=[elem[elem.value].getAttribute('type'), 
    elem[elem.value].getAttribute('primo'), 
    elem[elem.value].getAttribute('secondo')] //records the coordinates (strings, not numbers)
  index=changed_element.findIndex(element_exist); //controls if already exist
  console.log('index', index)
  console.log('element', element)

  if (index==-1) { //new element
    changed_element.push(element);
    changed_value.push(elem[elem.value].text);
  } else { //already exist, so update the value
    changed_value[index]=elem[elem.value].text;
  };

  function element_exist(array) {
    console.log('array', array)
    return array==element; //return the index of the element if already in list or -1
  };
});
```

But it doesn't work... index is always -1

Edit: now I understand what's happening below: the function is called once for element until it find a double /edit

also at first change the console.logs give:

```
index -1

element Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]
```

At the second change (on the same dropdown) give:

```
array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]

index -1 

element Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]
```

but array and element are the same so index should be 0... at third change (on the same dropdown) give:

```
array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]

array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ] //it add one more and so on

index -1

element Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]
```

Why it calls two times the function `element_exist`?

Now I change another dropdown and it gives:

```
array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]

array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]

array Array [ "whenever", "something", "someotherthing" ]

index -1

element Array [ "whenever new", "something new", "someotherthing new" ]
```

So element is different and the index is rightful -1 but the function `element_exist` is called three times.

Comment: What's the code of `element_exist`? In it, you can't compare two arrays like `array1 == array2`, you must do a one-by-one comparison.

Comment: Ops, that should be the error... you can see my element_exist above

Answer (score 0):

So, here my solution:

```
...
var changed_element=[]
var changed_value=[];

document.getElementById('tabella').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var elem = event.target; //detect the element changed
    var element=[elem[elem.value].getAttribute('type'), 
        elem[elem.value].getAttribute('primo'), 
        elem[elem.value].getAttribute('secondo')] //records the coordinates (strings, not numbers)
    var index=element_exist(changed_element, element); //controls if already exist

    if (index==-1) { //new element
        changed_element.push(element);
        changed_value.push(elem[elem.value].text);
    } else { //already exist, so update the value
        changed_value[index]=elem[elem.value].text;
    };

    function element_exist(changed_element, element) {
        for (i=0; i<changed_element.length; i++) {
            if (element[0]==changed_element[i][0] && element[1]==changed_element[i][1] && element[2]==changed_element[i][2]) {
                return i;
            };
        };
        return -1
    };
};
```

it don't use findIndex and that's better because many browser don't support it. Unlucky it works only if `len(element)=3` but for me it's ok